# Improve loops performance with parallelization

Tags: multithreading, performance, loops, parallel-processing, julia

So I'm trying to wrap my head around Julia's parallelization options. I'm modelling stochastic processes as Markov chains. Since the chains are independent replicates, the outer loops are independent - making the problem *embarrassingly parallel*.
I tried to implement both a `@distributed` and a `@threads` solution, both of which seem to run fine, but **aren't any faster** than the sequential.

Here's a simplified version of my code (sequential):

```julia
function dummy(steps = 10000, width = 100, chains = 4)
    out_N = zeros(steps, width, chains)
    initial = zeros(width)
    for c = 1:chains
        # print("c=$c\n")
        N = zeros(steps, width)
        state = copy(initial)
        N[1,:] = state
        for i = 1:steps
            state = state + rand(width)
            N[i,:] = state
        end
        out_N[:,:,c] = N
    end
    return out_N
end
```

What would be the correct way of parallelizing this problem to increase performance?

Comment: It looks like you're accessing your arrays using row-major indexing.  Julia's arrays are column major, so accessing `N[:, i]` will be faster.  Further, you may get even better performance if you move away from vectorized code.  Finally, multithreaded `rand` is often fastest if you manually specify the thread-local RNG.

Comment: Thank you for the tips @Matt, I will try them out. Vectorized code is definitely a habit from my first language, R, that I should work on.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the correct way to do it (at the time of writing this answer the other answer does not work - see my comment).

I will use slightly less complex example than in the question (however very similar).

#### 1. Not parallelized version (baseline scenario)

```
using Random
const m = MersenneTwister(0);

function dothestuff!(out_N, N, ic, m)
    out_N[:, ic] .= rand(m, N)
end

function dummy_base(m=m, N=100_000,c=256)
    out_N = Array{Float64}(undef,N,c)
    for ic in 1:c
        dothestuff!(out_N, N, ic, m)
    end
    out_N 
end
```

Testing:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools; @btime dummy_base();
  106.512 ms (514 allocations: 390.64 MiB)
```

#### 2. Parallelize with threads

```
#remember to run before starting Julia:
# set JULIA_NUM_THREADS=4
# OR (Linux)
# export JULIA_NUM_THREADS=4

using Random

const mt = MersenneTwister.(1:Threads.nthreads());
# required for older Julia versions, look still good in later versions :-)

function dothestuff!(out_N, N, ic, m)
    out_N[:, ic] .= rand(m, N)
end
function dummy_threads(mt=mt, N=100_000,c=256)
    out_N = Array{Float64}(undef,N,c)
    Threads.@threads for ic in 1:c
        dothestuff!(out_N, N, ic, mt[Threads.threadid()])
    end
    out_N 
end
```

Let us test the performance:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools; @btime dummy_threads();
  46.775 ms (535 allocations: 390.65 MiB)
```

#### 3. Parallelize with processes (on a single machine)

```
using Distributed

addprocs(4) 

using Random, SharedArrays
@everywhere using Random, SharedArrays, Distributed
@everywhere Random.seed!(myid())

@everywhere function dothestuff!(out_N, N, ic)
    out_N[:, ic] .= rand(N)
end
function dummy_distr(N=100_000,c=256)
    out_N = SharedArray{Float64}(N,c)
    @sync @distributed for ic in 1:c
        dothestuff!(out_N, N, ic)
    end
    out_N 
end
```

Performance (note that inter-process communication takes some time and hence for small computations threads will be usually better):

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools; @btime dummy_distr();
  62.584 ms (1073 allocations: 45.48 KiB)
```

Comment: Hi @Przemyslaw, thank you for your input. This looks promising. But again the code is semantically incorrect, I'm not trying to generate random matrices of independent elements.

Comment: The question was about correctly parallelizing computations. You still need to do your own job.

Comment: You said that for small computations `@threads` is usually better. Is it right that for large computations `@distributed` or even `@spawnat` would work faster, one a single machine?

Comment: `Distributed` keeps all processes separately and on larger code you will not run thinks such as deadlocks. When there is a big level of parallelization (more than 16) I empirically found that sharing an object is just not efficient - better to have processes with `Distributed`. on the other hand `Distributed` is heavy - interprocess communication just takes tones time.

Comment: You can halve the allocations by writing  `out_N[:, ic] .= rand.(m)`, instead of making a new vector every time. This makes it almost twice as quick for me. Writing `rand!(@view out_N[:, ic])` also works.

Comment: Yes indeed, very good point! However, this does not affect performance of the `SharedArray`so in that case the last example takes the longest time to execute which than is not a representative for typical usage of `Distributed`. Since I tried to make the code similar to the one in the question I think it will be better to leave it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @distributed macro, to run processes in parallel

```
@everywhere using Distributed, SharedArrays

addprocs(4)

@everywhere function inner_loop!(out_N, chain_number,steps,width)
    N = zeros(steps, width)
    state = zeros(width)
    for i = 1:steps
        state .+= rand(width)
        N[i,:] .= state
    end
    out_N[:,:,chain_number] .= N
    nothing
end

function dummy(steps = 10000, width = 100, chains = 4)
    out_N = SharedArray{Float64}((steps, width, chains); pids = collect(1:4))
    @sync for c = 1:chains
        # print("c=$c\n")
        @spawnat :any inner_loop!(out_N, c, steps,width)
    end
    sdata(out_N)
end
```

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for your answer. Your code is indeed blazing fast but semantically wrong. It generates random matrices, not Markov chains.

Comment: Your code snippet in the question generates random matrices as well, not Markov chains.

Comment: Mmh...no? It generates (dummy) MC in the sense that `N[i+1,:]`  depends on `N[i,:]`. Your matrix entries are fully independent elements. Check the outputs.

Comment: I edited code to match your needs. Now it should work properly

Comment: thank you @Paul. I had tried a similar `@distributed` solution. Unfortunately the `@time` macros seem to be misleading (systematically underestimating) for parallel code (probably not measuring overhead properly). If I manually time a larger calculation, say `dummy(1000000,100,10)`, I'm in the same range of performance as a sequential loop on my machine (laptop)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217607/discussion-between-paul-dydyshko-and-levasco).

Comment: You need to put `@sync` in both these definitions; otherwise you're just kicking off the tasks and not waiting for them to complete (hence the absurdly fast timings).

Comment: So I've got to put `@sync` right before `for` loop, am I right?

Comment: Yes.  But also `@async` is not true parallelism.  Use `Threads.@spawn` if you want multithreading.

Comment: Guys and Girls, both those code are totally wrong! The first one will not work because remote processes will not know about `inner_loop!` and the results will not be stored! The array will be passed in only one way to the remote  process. A `SharedArray` should be used instead. The macro `@async` spins a green thread and can be used to only speed-up IO-intesive loops (such as web scraping, file transfers etc.)

Comment: To make remote process know about `inner_loop!` I have to define it with `@everywhere` macro, is it true?